# Error creating bean with name 'webMvcRequestHandlerProvider'

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm new on Spring "things"
I use this version:

```
spring-boot-starter-parent
1.5.3-RELEASE
```

And I have this dependencies on the pom.xml

- io.springfox springfox-swagger2    2.8.0
- io.springfox springfox-swagger-ui 2.8.0

And I think this generated the error below, but I don't know why.

Can help me?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcRequestHandlerProvider' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/tjoel/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.8.0/springfox-spring-web-`enter code here`2.8.0.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
```

Comment: add more detail of your code so that others can analysis it

Comment: Hi, tanks for your help, but I resolve the problem. In proprieties file, i change the name of the aplication for the main packege.

Comment: You need add spring-context dependency. It solved my problem.

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.14.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2041):

> Its failing because you have multiple spring contexts going. You may have to experiment with removing/adding @Configuration and @EnableWebMvc configurations